# Difference between tf.constant and tf.Variable (trainable= False)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I came across some code where `tf.Variable(... trainable=False)` was used and I wondered whether there was any difference between using `tf.constant(...)` and `tf.Variable`(with the `trainable` argument set to False)

It seems a bit redundant to have the `trainable` argument option available with tf.constant is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few reasons I can tell you off the top of my head:

- If you declare a `tf.Variable`, you can change it's value later on if you want to. On the other hand, `tf.constant` is immutable, meaning that once you define it you can't change its value.
- Let's assume that you have a neural network with multiple weight matrices, for the first few epochs you can to train the last layer, while keeping the all the rest frozen. After that, for the last few epochs, you want to fine-tune the whole model. If the first layers are defined as `tf.constant`, you can't do that.

Comment: I defined,
my_tensor = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 5.0]])
later on when I execute the following it doen't give me any error
my_tensor = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
does it mean I can change its value.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other differences, but one that comes to mind is that, for some TF graphs, you want a variable to be trainable sometimes and frozen other times.  For example, for transfer learning with convnets you want to freeze layers closer to the inputs and only train layers closer to the output.  It would be inconvenient, I suppose, if you had to swap out all the tf.Variable layers for tf.constant layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare something with `tf.constant()` you won't be able to change the value in future. But, `tf.Variable()` let's you change the variable in future. You can assign some other value to it. If it is not trainable, then the gradient won't flow through it.